# Android Studio how to Revert Using Services instead of Run?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I would like to use the **`Run`** window in Android Studio for launching my run configurations (which is the default for projects).

---

I know that at some point I enabled the **`8. Services`** window to be the default for one of my projects, however, I have no idea how to disable this again:

[image: Screen capture]

Any time I run anything in said project (launch an app, run tests, a command line app, etc.), it is launched in this `Services` windows, which has a bunch of annoying downsides in my opinion.

---

I do not want to delete the entire `.idea` directory of the project because I have many settings that I do not want to lose - it is just this one that bugs me.

Comment: Please check "Configurations available in Services" list in "Run Configurations | Templates".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which run configurations are run in the **Services** window is determined by the `Configurations availabe in Services` list in `Run/Debug Configurations` `->` `Templates`:

[image: Capture]

In there, you can simply remove or add any configurations that you want to have run in `8. Services` or not.

#### Navigation

**`Run`** `->` **`Edit Configurations...`** `->` **`Templates`** `->` ***`Configurations available in Services`***

---

[Thanks to @y.bedrov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443635/android-studio-how-to-revert-using-services-instead-of-run?noredirect=1#comment108717121_61443635) for pointing it out.